# JavaScript check if an array contains same element at the same index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays-

```
var A =  ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"];
var B = [["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"], ["c", "a", "b", "a", "b"]];
R = [5, 2];
```

Need a result R = [5, 2] as in first element of B have same element as A and second element have only 2 elements similar at same index.

I tried an approach with map but its failing.

```
var o =  ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"];
var rS = [["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"], ["c", "a", "b", "a", "b"]];
var result = Array(rS.length).fill(0);

rS.map((e1,i1,a1)=>{
    e1.map((e2,i2,a2)=>{
        rS[i1][i2] === o[i1] ? result[i1]+=1 : result[i1]+=0;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could map `b` with the result of the count if the nested array item who match.

```js
var a =  ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"],
    b = [["a", "b", "c", "a", "b"], ["c", "a", "b", "a", "b"]],
    result = b.map(values =>
        values.reduce((count, value, index) => count + (value === a[index]), 0)
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this works:

```
var result = A.filter(e => B.indexOf(e) !== -1).length === B.length
console.log(result);
```